# How to use the combrowser.py within the pywin32 package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, com, pywin32

I'm using the package pywin32 to control some executables. To check the list of applications I would like to use the "combrowser.py". I'm trying to start the file, but I'm getting the message:

```
File "combrowse.py", line 540
    print "Warning - exiting with %d/%d objects alive" % (ni,ng)
                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My system:

- Windows 7 / 64 bits
- Python 3.7.1

Any idea?

Comment: That `print` statement is Python 2. That is why you are getting a syntax error. Nothing to do with `pywin32`.

Comment: Man, I have programmed python since 2016, but I'm a noob yet, XD. Thanks a lot. I'm going to check and report.

Comment: It's solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a wrong version of python (3.7 intead 2.7) to try to run this program. After, I installed the pywin32 package and searched at the site-package folder. It's a little bit of mess, but I found the candidates folders for search:

- pywin32_system32
- pywin32-224.dist-info
- win32com
- win32comnext

I noted that the folder starting with "pywin32" were almost empty with some dll files and other data. Thereafter, I tried win32com folder and searched a little bit. I found the "combrowser.py"!

Just runned normaly and worked.